# How do i create a navigation function that returns websites in my composite c1 portal?

Tags: asp.net, razor, c1-cms

I want to create a function (prefer razor) that returns a list of websites in my portal.

I found @HomePageNode and able to process childs from there, but thats only the active website.

I added another website next to the defaut "Front Page" and would like to put in a switcher at the top automatic if i add others also later.

Composite C1 is a CMS System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Composite.Data.SitemapNavigator.HomepageNodes`](http://api.composite.net/html/P_Composite_Data_SitemapNavigator_HomePageNodes.htm):

> Gets PageNode's for all homepages.

Example:

```
using(var conn = new DataConnection())
{
    var navigator = new SitemapNavigator(conn);
    IEnumerable<PageNode> homePageNodes = navigator.HomePageNodes;
}
```

Now you have the PageNodes of all your homepages and can traverse them recursively via `ChildNodes`.

---

There also are other functions in SitemapNavigator you might prefer depending on your circumstances, like `AllSitemapsXML` or `HomepageIDs`.

You will find them all in the [Composite API](http://api.composite.net/html/AllMembers_T_Composite_Data_SitemapNavigator.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Are there an easy way to attach some properties to each homepagenodes ? (my menu needs some colour properties to render its menu). Or should i go ahead ad create my own global datatype and add items for entry i want in my menu?

Comment: Have a look at Page MetaData Types.